# setting default columns in org column mode into init file

Tags: org-mode, column

Trying to set preferred columns in ORG column mode.
this works perfectly if I put it on head of the file:

```
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %TAGS %PRIORITY %TODO %CLOSED %SCHEDULED
```

But I avoid to repeat it for every org file and tried to put it on init file, to no avail:

```
(setq org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%45ITEM %TAGS %PRIORITY %TODO %CLOSED %SCHEDULED")
```

Comment: The doc says: "Don’t set this, this is meant for dynamic scoping."

Answer (score 0):

The variable to set seems to be `org-columns-default-format`. The doc string says:

> org-columns-default-format is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
>   Its value is "%25ITEM %TODO %3PRIORITY %TAGS"
>
> Documentation:
>   The default column format, if no other format has been defined.
>   This variable can be set on the per-file basis by inserting a line
>
> #+COLUMNS: %25ITEM .....
>
> You can customize this variable.